# Qt C++ QtWebKit Application

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qweb, qwebkit

I made a web browser using qtwebkit. Site I want to enter without applying "http://atlas". This is subversion repository. I need username and password prompt. But , There is no direct authorization saying no authorization.

```
void WebBrowser::on_webView_loadStarted()
{
    ui->webView->load(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

[image: Output]

FireFox Browser wants this user login as follows,Why is not it the same?

Comment: Check: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qauthenticator.html

Comment: I thinks I understood your question. You are expecting to enter credentials onLoadStarted? It is your job to show this popup! When load finishes and based on http status code, you should show a credential popup instead of loading the page in your main area. Then reload using maybe QAuthenticator if it supports the type of authentication of your server.